# compilation Error: unexpected TOKEN_Function

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

This is the error i get:

> Error [mod0000_mergedfiles]game\gui\main_menu\ingamemenu.ws(2179): syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_FUNCTION, expecting '{' or ';', near 'function'.

To clarify the line with the syntax error is 2179.

And here is the entire script: https://pastebin.com/UsUjJ1rY.

```
function ShouldHideDLCIcons():bool
   
    {
        return theGame.GetInGameConfigWrapper().GetVarValue('fhudMainMenu', 'fhudHideDLC');
    }
```

Comment: This isn’t JavaScript. Please use correct tags. Please include an [mre] that reproduces the error. Please include your research about this issue.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting this to be JavaScript, based on the question tag and the pastebin link. If you're trying run the script as JavaScript, that's why it's not working.

Comment: @AnnieP You wouldn’t get the error _“syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_FUNCTION”_ if you ran this as JavaScript.

Comment: honestly, i tried googleing on the problem and it just came up that its a Javascrip, its mod scripts for The Witcher 3,

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit accordingly. As is, this Q is likely to be removed, as it is not conducive for volunteers to quickly identify the issue and provide a solution, as it does not meet guidelines for questions that SO is designed to handle. To be clear code and all info must be embedded in the question, and all code not relevant to reproducing  the issue must be removed, to provide focus on the issue.

Comment: A quick search shows that is has its own language: [Witcher  Script](https://witcher.gamepedia.com/Witcher_Script)